# How would I select rows in pandas that match a list of strings, not just one particular string?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a dataframe- df and a column labelled 'A'. For selecting rows that match ONE string -'some_string',     df['A'].str.contains('some_string') works great.

My question is, is there a corresponding method to pass to contains a list of strings, so that partial matches can be gotten? instead of 'some_string' can I give it a list of strings? I am trying to avoid using a for loop and slicing the data frame and concatenating into a new dataframe.

Lets say the dataframe is

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([['cat', 2], ['rat', 5], ['ball', 8],['string', 8]]),columns=['A', 'B']))
```

and

```
list =['at','ll','ac']
```

So I want to select the rows with cat, rat, ball. Sorry for the artificially contrived example.

Comment: can you create a example df and an expected df? this would help us replicate your question. :) Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use `df['A'].str.contains("|".join(list_of_strings))`.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if string in pandas dataframe column is in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972938/check-if-string-in-pandas-dataframe-column-is-in-list)

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49641417/3337089) as well. We can write any logic in the lambda function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) takes either a string or a regex. So you could just build a regex from the list of strings:

```
import pandas as pd

strings = "fo", "ba"
x = pd.Series(["foo", "bar", "baz", "buzz"])
x.str.contains("|".join(strings))
# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2     True
 #3    False
# dtype: bool
```

This might be slow if your list of strings to match against is very long and you might need a `na=False` to ignore `NaN` values, as [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049312/how-would-i-select-rows-in-pandas-that-match-a-list-of-strings-not-just-one-par/55049423?noredirect=1#comment96848969_55049423) by [@anky_91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840637/anky-91).

Comment: also add` `na=False` just incase. :)

Answer (score 2):

The most simplistic and Pandas friendly is:

```
list_of_strings = ['string1', 'string2']

df[df['A'].isin(list_of_strings)]
```

From https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

If `A` always contains exactly the string you want to find in the list, you can do this:

```
df['A'].map(lambda x: 1 if x in list_of_strings else 0)
```

the lambda function will check, for each row, if the value in `'A'` (temporarily stored in `x` exists as one of the elements in `list_of_strings`, and return `1` or `0` accordingly.

You can then filter when this new mapped column is `1`

Comment: will this work with substring matching? instead of if x in list_of_strings can I say contains?

Comment: Yes, but it is probably not very efficient. You can use a list comprehension:

`lambda x: True in [x in s for s in list_of_strings]`

Comment: @Tacratis You should use `any(...)` instead of `True in [...]`.